# Angular UI-Select: How to add a tooltip for text overflow?

Tags: angularjs, hover, tooltip, overflow, ui-select

I have a ui-select-match element, and when opening the element and hovering (highlighting) over a row I need a tooltip to show the full content of the row in case of text overflow that is cut off by the border.

It seems like something that should have been a feature of ui-select but I couldn't find any reference for such a thing. So far I only found solutions that show the entire text inside the row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

What about putting `title="{{selected.name}}"` on the element holding the `ui-select-match` directive. The tooltip will be in any case though, not only when text overflows.

Code:

```
<ui-select ng-model="address.selected"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="disabled"
             reset-search-input="false"
             style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match title="{{address.selected.formatted_address}}" placeholder="Enter an address...">{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
             refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"
             refresh-delay="0">
      <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

See **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VZKNuW2XsjVnQ9eFZ398?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about it as an option but I need the tooltip to show only with text overflows.